# How to access NFS shares from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, nfs

We have a group of users who run Windows and access files on a Linux box. Historically, they've been on XP and we run Samba on the Linux box. No problem.

Now we're testing Windows 7 and finding interoperability to be a huge pain between the older version of Samba (the Linux box is running Ubuntu 8.04) and Windows 7.

I'd like to use NFS instead, but the information out there on how to do this is confusing. Apparently you're supposed to install "Client for NFS" from Windows 7's "Turn Windows features on or off" dialog, but I don't see anything NFS related there. I've also seen guides which go into a huge amount of detail explaining how you need to map users between Windows and Linux, but then other places suggest that accessing NFS from Windows only requires a simple mount command or mapping a drive using server:/share syntax.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Services for NFS in windows features you need to check off client for NFS.  I beleive this requires profesional or better (I don't have anything under enterprise available to verify)

Comment: Yeah after much frustration it seems that it's only available in Enterprise and Ultimate, despite many claims that it's available on Professional, which is part of the reason I was getting very confused. I'll install Enterprise instead of Pro and see how it goes.